# Node formula of a different kind of binary search tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the max number of nodes in a tree that is defined as follows:

The root can have at most 2 children.
Each subtree on the left can have at most L children.
Each subtree on the right can have at most R children.

I know the formula for finding the number nodes in a binary tree is 2^h-1, where h is the amount of levels in the tree.

How would this be approached in layman's terms? (I am not extremely mathy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So more formally, you are trying to find the number of nodes in a binary search tree such that the root of the tree has two children, and each subtree on the left has at most l children and each subtree on the right has r children.

We can consider the left and right trees separately, since they don't affect each other's height. Disregarding the root, let's call the left subtree of the root *L* and let's call the right subtree of the root *R*. *L* holds the invariant that each node in *L* cannot have more than *l* children. Similarly, each node in *R* cannot have more than *r* children.

Let's construct two function, *b* and *c*, that take height *h* and output the maximum number of nodes in *L* or *R* respectively.

```
b(h) = if h = 1 then 1 else l * b(h - 1)
c(h) = if h = 1 then 1 else r * b(h - 1)
```

Now, we can construct function *a* that takes height *h* and outputs the maximum nodes of the tree you defined.

```
a(h) = if h = 1 then 1 else (b(h - 1) + c(h - 1))
```

Now, we want to find a closed form for *a*. Let's start by finding the closed forms for *b* and *c*.

Given positive height *h*, since l is being repeatedly multiplied except for the first case,

```
b(h) = l^(h - 1)
c(h) = r^(h - 1)
a(h) = if h = 1 then 1 else (l^(h - 1) + r^(h - 1))
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to also consider *h* = 1 within the closed form for *a*, but given *h* > 1, the formula for finding the maximum number of nodes of the binary search tree you defined, is

```
l^(h - 1) + r^(h - 1)
```